# Why is "False" in the condition part of for loop showing an error but "True" works perfectly?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

```
for(int i=0;true;i++){
    System.out.println("hi");
    break;
}

for(int i=0;false;i++){
    System.out.println("hi");
    break;
}
```

The first code is executing perfectly but the second code is showing the following error:

```
prog.java:12: error: unreachable statement
    for(int i=0; false;i++){
                           ^
```

1 error

Comment: You forgot to include the error message.

Comment: Please show us the error.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Yeah, sorry. I've added now.

Comment: -1 because it's not an "execution error" but a compile error. The error message which you got is very clear. So why you are asking here?

Comment: It might not be clear to a beginner though. Especially if he did not understand how loop conditions work or was not able to link the error message to the `false` condition.

Comment: A loop is only entered and executed as long as its condition resolves to `true`. Your condition is just `false`, thus the loop will never be entered. As if you do `if (false) { ... }`, it will never enter. Making the code inside your loop unreachable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few points to learn here.

1. When the compiler can detect, at compile time, that a part of the code is not reachable, it will mark it as such to help you detect the problem as quickly as possible. So in an `if` statement whose condition is known to be `false`, the statement part is unreachable, and marked as such.
2. Loops like `for (init; condition;expr) statement` and `while (condition) statement` check their condition before running the statement even once. Thus, if the condition is `false`, the statement will never be executed. So the same thing happens like in the `if` statement with `false` condition.
3. The condition has to be resolved at compile time. Something like

   ```
   boolean a = false;
   while (a) ...
   ```

   is not considered to be known at compile time, but `false` and `true` are known at compile time, because they are literal.
4. It doesn't happen with `true`, because when the compiler known the condition is `true`, it knows the loop will be entered at least once. Thus, there is no analogous error for `true`, and in fact, loops of the type `while (true)...` are quite common.

Answer (score 3):

The error you get is:

> Unreachable statement

and it refers to the code inside the `for` block.
This means that the line:

```
System.out.println("hi");
```

will never be executed because the condition (*termination expression*) of `for` is right from the start (and will always be) `false`.
Find more about for here: [The for Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)

Answer (score 3):

Unreachable code in Java is a compilation error. In the second for loop you've written, 'false' means that the control would never enter the 'for loop body', making it unreachable code, and hence a compilation error.

Comment: Not necessarily true.  Dead code can also be unreachable but is not a compilation error.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that some situations which the compiler could detect as unreachable code are flagged as dead code.  For example:

This compiles and runs just fine (although the default in Eclipse is to issue a warning).

```java
   public int foo() {
      if (true) {
         return 10;
      }
      return 5; // dead code (but it is definitely unreachable).
   }
```

On the other hand, here is also something the compiler could recognize as unreachable code but doesn't (fortunately).

`DEBUG` can never change during program execution. Guaranteed by `final`. Yet the code compiles just fine and runs.  In fact, the entire `if clause` is removed and doesn't appear in the byte code.  This can be useful for sprinkling statements like this in your code and then removing them by simply changing DEBUG from true to false.

```java
   final static boolean DEBUG = false; 
   public int bar(int v) {

      if (DEBUG) {
         System.out.println("v = " + v);
      }
      return v*5;
   }
```